# Can I add more swap space to my system to goes fluenly?

Tags: swap

I'd like to add more RAM to my system, but as I see in tutorials how they have no swap space as I do. You can see the result of `sudo swapon --show`.

```
lindor@lenovo:~$ sudo swapon --show
[sudo] lindor jelszava: 
NAME       TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile  file      3,9G   0B   -2
/dev/zram0 partition 1,9G   0B    5
```

Can I add more space or something is wrong with these datas?
I do not want to cause any problem in my laptop's system.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: *"... but as I see in tutorials how they have no swap space as I do."* Do you mean that in the tutorials you watch they have more swap than you, or that they do not have swap at all?

Comment: (1) With software you are adding swap space, not "more RAM". (2) You haven't specified the actual physical RAM on your system and the memory you need or typically use. (3) The `zram` thing is not a default thing in Ubuntu AFAIK. Did you follow some tutorial for that?